# My iOS app hangs on saving with mulithreading

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, objective-c-blocks

My iOS app hangs on savaging when i segue between 2 screens a couple of times.
it belongs to store the data but than this just freeze with no errors.
Somebody any idea how i can fix this ?

```
self.fetchF = dispatch_queue_create(label, NULL);
dispatch_async(self.fetchF, ^{

    NSArray *feeds = [FeedFetcher getData:self.pageTitle downloadBy:@"up"];

    NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = self.managedObject;

    for (NSDictionary *feedInfo in feeds) {
        [Feed FeedWithInfo:feedInfo InManageObject:newContext];
    }

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        if (newContext != self.managedObject)
            [newContext save:&error];

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error save : %@", error);

        [self setupFetchedResultsController];

        [self downloadImages:feeds];
    });        
});
```

Edit :

I change my managedobjectcontext so it has every thread a new one.
But now when i segue between 2 screens a couple of times it freeze on [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]; With no errors..
Does somebody a idea for a solution ?

```
- (void)performFetch
{
    if (self.fetchedResultsController) {
        if (self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate) {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching %@ with predicate: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName, self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate);
        } else {
            if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] fetching all %@ (i.e., no predicate)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entityName);
        }
        NSError *error;
        if (self.fetchedResultsController != nil)
            [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

        if (error) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] %@ (%@)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    } else {
        if (self.debug) NSLog(@"[%@ %@] no NSFetchedResultsController (yet?)", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: are you sure you're jsut using the context within the thread it has been created in?

Comment: I create it in the app delegate class. And i give it to the class where i have to use it. Every time i use NSManagedObjectContext *newContext = self.managedObject;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is generally not thread-safe. Rule of thumb is to create a `NSManagedObjectContext` per thread. I believe you're reusing your context among threads and that's causing the problem.

Docs on Core Data concurrency:

> Core Data uses thread (or serialized queue) confinement to protect
>   managed objects and managed object contexts (see “Concurrency with
>   Core Data”). A consequence of this is that a context assumes the
>   default owner is the thread or queue that allocated it—this is
>   determined by the thread that calls its init method. You should not,
>   therefore, initialize a context on one thread then pass it to a
>   different thread. Instead, you should pass a reference to a persistent
>   store coordinator and have the receiving thread/queue create a new
>   context derived from that. If you use NSOperation, you must create the
>   context in main (for a serial queue) or start (for a concurrent
>   queue).